# Xcode - Building for Multiple Targets Simultaneously

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have one Xcode project with multiple targets. During development, it is becoming laborious to compile and install each separately.

Is there a way, through scripting or otherwise; that I can automate the build and install to device of multiple targets at once.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Within a target, you can add other targets as dependencies.  So pick one that's going to be your "master" target, or just create another target to act as a container for all your other targets, add your other targets as dependencies, and build that.

Comment: This works partially; I created a new "Aggregator" target to which I added all the other Targets as Dependencies in Build Phases. However, this builds everything but does not install everything to the device. Which is what I would like ultimately..

Comment: Ahh I see.  As far as I know it only installs to the device when you start a debug session with a build target.  I don't know if it's possible to debug multiple targets at once on an iOS device.

Answer (score 15):

Have you tried using `xcodebuild` from the command line?

```
xcodebuild -project projName -alltargets
```

`man xcodebuild` will list all available options.

Answer (score 11):

`xcodebuild` does also support multiple targets it just does not say it anywhere in the man page or documentation

```
xcodebuild -target targ1 -target targ2
```

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode, within Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes, you'll see a list of schemes that were automatically added, i.e. one scheme for each target in the project.  Edit the active scheme, then from the Build phase of that scheme add the secondary target.  Now when you clean or build this project using the active scheme, it will clean or build both targets.

Note: the active scheme is shown checked on the Product > Scheme menu.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for posting this.